# application slowness on specific version of jdk

Tags: java, java-8

My java web application performance drops when i run on JDK 1.8.0_151. 
I checked with previous versions jdk8 like (141,131,121) it runs without any slowness.

I am calculating the time difference between request received and response sending time as the application processing time.

So i would like to know on what facts this is happening, does it depends upon the third party library that are used, or the application server(resin in my case) not supporting this version of JDK, or any other factors.

Any of your advise on this is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: *"Your advise on this is appreciated."*  - Use a profiler to compare the performance of the application on different platforms.   It is impossible for anyone else to predict the cause from the scant information that you have provided.  And even if we could, it would only be a **guess**.

Comment: Stephen, i have considered profiling on different platforms, but its something unexpected what i feel an application should not slow down on a particular jdk. please let me know if any information is lacking